# Change font for cmd.exe (not legacy)

Tags: windows-10, console

How can I add fonts to the *new* console?

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont`

The answers to the other questions, that add a registry key to the above, do NOT work. Adding the font there can be seen if you enable legacy mode, but otherwise does not work.

I do not want to enable legacy mode because I use the new features: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt427362.aspx

Comment: It needs to be a proper monospaced font.  If it is, then it should just be available in the Fonts tab of the console (once installed into Windows). Which font are you trying to use?

Comment: With some exceptions, I can see all fonts with `FIXED_PITCH`.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 in the Windows\Fonts\ directory it is called "Fixedsys Regular"